# Do these formula applies to Frustrum of a right pyramid which have a regular polygon as a base?

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

So here is the problem:

A baking pan has a rectangular base 12 inches by 8 inches; the sides and ends of the pan slope outward, so that the upper edges measure respectively 13.5 inches by 9 inches. If the depth of the pan is 2 inches, find the amount of cake batter required to fill the pan to one-half its depth.

I answered the problem and here is my solution and apologize for my bad drawing and bad grammar:

[Pyramid Frustrum and Its Dimensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ifb68.jpg)

[Front View Calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBeH9.jpg)

[Side View Calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdjMQ.jpg)

[Final Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1LNy.jpg)

But I wanted to solve the problem with different approach, in here I applied this formula from similar figures:

[Similar Figures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXH0g.png)

Then I noticed if I calculate the base if the height is half, then they do not have the same value:

[Lengths does not match](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0KZ5.jpg)

Is the formula that I am using is invalid or I am using it wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I get $102 \frac 18$, too.  This is the method using calculus $\int_0^1 (12 + \frac 34 t)(8 + \frac 12 t) \ dt = \int_0^1 96 + 12 t + \frac 38  t^2 \ dt = 96 + 6+\frac 18 = 102 \frac 18$